# Convert text file of multiple types to matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, io, octave

I'm using the iris dataset and it looks as follows...

```
5.4,3.7,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.4,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.0,1.4,0.1,Iris-setosa
4.3,3.0,1.1,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.8,4.0,1.2,0.2,Iris-setosa
...
```

As you can see there are different types in the data. The first few are floats and the final one is a string. Because of this I cannot use `dlmread`. When I try it, I get errors.

I tried using `fscanf` but my solution does not give me what I want...

```
filename = "train.txt"
A = fopen(filename, 'r')
data = fscanf(A, '%f %f %f %f %s')
```

This is giving `data` as a 1x1 array.

What I want is to convert the data into a matrix where I can access values by row and column. So, `data(1,1)` would be `5.4`. I am not that familiar with I/O in Octave so your help is appreciated.

Comment: Try : `pkg load io; data = csv2cell("train.txt");`

Comment: Your `fscanf` format string is missing commas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me, both in Matlab R2017a and in Octave 4.2.1. For more information see [`textscan` documentation](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html).

```
fid = fopen('filename.txt');
x = textscan(fid, '%f,%f,%f,%f,%s');
fclose(fid);
x_num = [x{1:4}];
x_str = x{5};
```

This gives

```
x_num =
   5.400000000000000   3.700000000000000   1.500000000000000   0.200000000000000
   4.800000000000000   3.400000000000000   1.600000000000000   0.200000000000000
   4.800000000000000   3.000000000000000   1.400000000000000   0.100000000000000
   4.300000000000000   3.000000000000000   1.100000000000000   0.100000000000000
   5.800000000000000   4.000000000000000   1.200000000000000   0.200000000000000

x_str =
  5×1 cell array
    'Iris-setosa'
    'Iris-setosa'
    'Iris-setosa'
    'Iris-setosa'
    'Iris-setosa'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily achieve this by using the [textscan function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) with the parameter `CollectOutput` set to `true`;

> Logical indicator determining data concatenation, specified as the
>   comma-separated pair consisting of 'CollectOutput' and either true or
>   false. If true, then the importing function concatenates consecutive
>   output cells of the same fundamental MATLAB® class into a single
>   array.

Example:

```
filename = 'train.txt';
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
data = textscan(fid,'%f%f%f%f%s','CollectOutput',true,'Delimiter',',');
fclose(fid);
```

The `data` variable will be returned in the form of a cell array in which the file contents will be grouped based on the underlying type. The first cell will contain the numeric values, while the second one the string values... and you can retrieve them separately as follows:

```
numerics = data{1};
texts = data{2};
```

Answer (score 0):

[Regular experssions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html) can be very helpful in problems like this. They allow you to search for a particular pattern or patterns. For example, using [regexp](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) you can find all instances of a pattern in your datasheet and read them into an array, with `out = regexp(str, expression, 'match')`. Depending on how you set up the program, it'll likely read it in as a 1xn array. But if you know the number of columns in each row, you can easily convert to an array with something like [vec2mat](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html).